# EF Code First recursive Query with IEnumerable<>?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a "Menu" table which has a ParentId column. My LINQ query is right below.

```
    public IEnumerable<MenuTableObject> GetMenus ( int? parentId ) {
        var result = ( from m in _db.Menus
                       join ml in _db.MenuLanguages on m.Id equals ml.MenuId
                       join l in _db.Languages on ml.LanguageId equals l.Id
                       where l.Code == Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name
                             && m.ParentId == ( parentId.HasValue ? parentId : null )
                       select new MenuTableObject {
                           Action = m.Action,
                           Controller = m.Controller,
                           Id = m.Id,
                           Title = ml.Title,
                           SubMenus = this.GetMenus( m.Id )
                       } );

        return result;
    }
```

And here is the MenuTableObject class.

```
public class MenuTableObject {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MenuTableObject> SubMenus { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the exception i get below.

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[IstanbulHairCenter.Data.Service.MenuTableObject] GetMenus(System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

What do i have to do to get over this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb you cannot use custom functions in any EF `IQueryable` queries (there may be an extensibility point, not sure though).

Each `IQueryable` query is an [expression tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx), not a func (notice that the `IQueryable` `Where()` takes an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` rather than `Func<T, bool>`). The tree is the analyzed by the specific implementation (Entity framework in this case) and mapped into a SQL string.

Each mapping must be explicitly created by the implementor. EF is telling you that it has no idea what to do with your `GetMenus()` method (ie the mapping from `GetMenus()` -> SQL does not exist).

The way around it is to pull all the relevant data out of the DB and then run you Query using LINQ to Object rather than LINQ to Entities.

The recursion is not the real cause. You need to use `ToList()` (or `AsEnumerable()` - not sure on that one though) on your entities sometime before the first recursive `GetMenus()` is called. Or you could write an StoredProc or something and call it off the context or the `DbSet`.

Comment: @lain: It is possible to have some limited extensions to `IQueryable`. There was an (unofficial) Microsoft project which allowed for it. I can't remember the name of it though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through the result outside the LINQ query to populate `SubMenus` because EF can not convert `GetMenus` method to SQL.

```
public IEnumerable<MenuTableObject> GetMenus ( int? parentId ) {
    var result = ( from m in _db.Menus
                   join ml in _db.MenuLanguages on m.Id equals ml.MenuId
                   join l in _db.Languages on ml.LanguageId equals l.Id
                   where l.Code == Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name
                         && m.ParentId == ( parentId.HasValue ? parentId : null )
                   select new MenuTableObject {
                       Action = m.Action,
                       Controller = m.Controller,
                       Id = m.Id,
                       Title = ml.Title
                   } ).ToList();

    foreach(var menu in result)
    {
        menu.SubMenus = this.GetMenus(menu.Id);
    }

    return result;
}
```